# Geocoding house numbers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding

I have a point feature class with residential information, but all that it has in terms of geographic information is the residence's house number.  There is no other information (street, zip, etc).  JUST house numbers.  The points fall more or less where they are located, but they are somewhat off.  I'm working off of a ArcMap basemap and I sometimes I can just move the points to areas that are obvious to me, for example if there's one point in a general area close to a house, and that's the only house, then its obvious to me that that point is that house.  However, i need a faster way to do this, and I need help with points that aren't so obvious, like for example when i have to assign a point to a residence and there are several residences to choose from.

I thought about geocoding, but I'm not sure how this would work when all I have to work with is a house number.

So I thought I could download a shapefile (maybe tiger data) with street names as well as zip codes, and do some kind of spatial join to where the points (house numbers) would be assigned the street name and zip code nearest the point.  and then create an address locator to match the points to the actual locations based on those attributes (street name, house number, and zip code).

Would this be a good way to tackle this? Does anyone have any other suggestions that might be better?  Could you maybe explain to me how I might do this? I'm pretty new to GIS and not very familiar with geocoding.
Also, can someone explain to me more or less how I should perform this spatial join?

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. I think there isn't going to be a good way to scrub this kind of data. Moving points in this way is almost certainly going to require some personal judgement. It might help if you can specify exactly what tools you have.

Comment: How do you intend to geocode something of which you don't know the position? I guess there are a million houses with the same number.

Answer (score 1):

The Spatial Join Tool is easy to use. It is located in the Analysis Toolbox, Overlay Toolset. This tool is available for any license level. To run this tool, select your Point featureclass for the Target_features and select the TIGER street line feature class for the Join_features. The output should be a Point feature class with the TIGER attributes included. Using SelectLayerByAttribute, you can find Points that are outside the min/max address range of the Joined Street. These Points are joined to an incorrect address. Also, from the Table View, you can Export the Point Addresses as a text file for use in a Geocoding Service.